# Why StreamWriter can't access the closed stream but StreamReader can?

Tags: c#, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter

If I write following statements.

```
fileStream.Close();
reader.Close();
writer.Close();
```

reader.Close() statement executes successfully. But I get error "Can't open closed file." on 3rd statement writer.Close()

If I write

```
fileStream.Close();
writer.Close();
reader.Close();
```

2nd statement i.e. writer.Close() itself throws the same exception.

Does anyone have idea?

Comment: My guess is that the writer might be trying to flush an internal buffer to the stream, which the reader obviously does not need to do.

Comment: And as a 'solution', just close the stream last. But better to use `using(){}` blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's because writer calls flush() before closing the underlying stream.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to have to guess that your code looks similar to do:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(...);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
...
```

Don't close fileStream, the stream writer now 'owns' the stream.  Closing it closes the file stream as well.

Comment: But as a matter of course I would wrap _both_ in using blocks. The Stream.Dispose will be a dummy but as long as it's last that's OK.

Comment: @Henk - Well, the dots might well be the last curly brace } of a method.  No using using.  This is why Close() exists in the first place.  The programming pattern is legit, albeit a bit fishy.